# How to make an empty view for JavaFX TabPane

Tags: java, javafx

Sorry if this question has been answer previously, but I'm having a hard time finding it (I'm probably just not searching for the right stuff).

I have a `TabPane` with tabs that can be closed.  When all the tabs are closed, I'm presented with an empty pane.  Is there a way to have a custom message displayed in this empty area?

I've thought of just stacking a view on top and binding it's visibility to the tab count == 0, but I know the several JavaFX controls (such as the `ListView`, `TableView`, and `TreeView`) have this functionality built in, and I was wondering if there was a similar built in (or at least simple) method for doing so with a `TabPane`.

P.S. I am aware that the `TabPane` is a container and not a control so it won't work the same as the controls I mentioned, but I can't imagine this use case has never come up.

Answer (score -1):

Could you use a StackPane which contains TabPane. Handle tab close event and if no tabs add a custom pane containing text to the StackPane?

Comment: That's basically what I said I can do in the question. I'm trying to find if there is a mechanism built in for this scenario. It seems there should be, but I haven't found one and now I don't believe there is one.

Comment: Maybe I'll have to submit a feature request